# Using Execute Immediate with FORALL for Update Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle19c

I Require to update a table based on data fetched from a query.
however in query I am generating Column Name and its respective values using LISTAGG.
I am able to update the table using the row by row processing with simple loop however I am exploring ways to utilize the FORALL with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE since I am changing the SET clause of UPDATE statement runtime.

```
set serveroutput on;

DECLARE 
l_sql VARCHAR2(4000);
cursor c1 is SELECT 
    OFFER_MIGRATION_ID,
    listagg(column_name||' = nvl('||column_name||','''||DEFAULT_CHAR_VALUE||''')', ','||chr(13)) within group (order by column_name) as set_clause
FROM
(
SELECT  distinct och.OFFER_MIGRATION_ID,
        och.ATTR_ID,
        ch_map.COLUMN_NAME,
        coalesce(och_list.value_name,och.DEFAULT_CHAR_VALUE) as DEFAULT_CHAR_VALUE
 FROM OFFERING_CHARS och,
      CHAR_MAP ch_map,
      OFFERING_CHARS_list och_list
Where ch_map.transformation = 'CONSTANT_DICT'
  and ch_map.attr_id = och.ATTR_ID
  and och.DEFAULT_CHAR_VALUE is not null
  and och_list.offer_migration_id(+) = och.offer_migration_id
  and och_list.characteristic_id(+) = och.characteristic_id
  and och_list.value(+) = och.DEFAULT_CHAR_VALUE
)
GROUP BY OFFER_MIGRATION_ID;  

TYPE char_list IS TABLE OF c1%rowtype index by pls_integer;
l_char_list char_list;
BEGIN 

/******** CONSTANT_FROM_DICT *********/
open c1;
fetch c1 bulk collect into l_char_list;
close c1;

FORALL i IN l_char_list.first .. l_char_list.last

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE product_char SET :1 WHERE offer_migration_id = '||l_char_list(i).offer_migration_id
    using l_char_list(i).set_clause;
 
 COMMIT;
 
END;
```

This block gives error --

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 35, column 92:
PLS-00440: FORALL bulk IN-bind variables cannot be used here
ORA-06550: line 35, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 35, column 5:
PLS-00435: DML statement without BULK In-BIND cannot be used inside FORALL
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

The values for set_clause column from the cursor will be like for example --

```
OFFER_MIGRATION_ID, SET_CLAUSE

10001   "CCA_CATEGORY = nvl(CCA_CATEGORY,'PD'),CCA_LIFECYCLE_STATUS = nvl(CCA_LIFECYCLE_STATUS,'A'),EQUIPMENT_TYPE = nvl(EQUIPMENT_TYPE,'Devices')"
20001   DATA_ALLOWANCE_SO = nvl(DATA_ALLOWANCE_SO,'9225')
20023   "DURATION = nvl(DURATION,'6'),DATA_ALLOWANCE_SUP_OFFER = nvl(DATA_ALLOWANCE_SUP_OFFER,'9203')"
20024   DATA_ALLOWANCE_SUP_OFFER = nvl(DATA_ALLOWANCE_SUP_OFFER,'9203')
```

My DB is -

```
Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
```

The loop which is working inside the PLSQL block I am looking for ways to better implement it instead of going row by row since it takes long time to execute.

```
FOR i IN 1..l_char_list.COUNT
 LOOP
    l_sql := 'UPDATE stgdm_product_char SET '||chr(13)||l_char_list(i).set_clause||chr(13)||' WHERE offer_migration_id = '||l_char_list(i).offer_migration_id;
--    dbms_output.put_line(l_sql);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql;
 END LOOP;
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the `product_char`, `offering_chars`, char_map` and `offering_chars_list` tables (and any others that are used); the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; and the expected output.

Comment: A bind variable is only for a value. You cannot reference columns or table names in bind variables. That is why it fails.

Comment: @KoenLostrie, Yes just wondering if we can still do it with some work arounds !!

Comment: @mradul hard to say without a proper reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need it to be so complicated. Since the destination table has a known, fixed set of columns then you can just white-list those columns in a `PIVOT` clause and then use a `MERGE` statement (then you only need a single SQL statement and do not need dynamic SQL).

Since you have not provided a proper [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I have combined all three of your input tables `OFFERING_CHARS`, `CHAR_MAP` and `OFFERING_CHARS_list` into a single table `your_combined_tables` which is much simpler to reverse engineer:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_combined_tables(
  offer_migration_id, column_name, default_char_value
) AS
SELECT 10001, 'CCA_CATEGORY',             'PD'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10001, 'CCA_LIFECYCLE_STATUS',     'A'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10001, 'EQUIPMENT_TYPE',           'Devices' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20001, 'DATA_ALLOWANCE',           '9225'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20023, 'DURATION',                 '6'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20023, 'DATA_ALLOWANCE_SUP_OFFER', '9203'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20024, 'DATA_ALLOWANCE_SUP_OFFER', '9203'    FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE product_char(
  offer_migration_id       NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  cca_category             VARCHAR2(20),
  cca_lifecycle_status     VARCHAR2(20),
  equipment_type           VARCHAR2(20),
  data_allowance           VARCHAR2(20),
  duration                 VARCHAR2(20),
  data_allowance_sup_offer VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO product_char (offer_migration_id)
SELECT 10001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20023 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20024 FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can use:

```sql
MERGE INTO product_char dst
USING (
  SELECT *
  FROM   your_combined_tables
  PIVOT  (
    MAX(default_char_value)
    FOR column_name IN (
      'CCA_CATEGORY'             AS cca_category,
      'CCA_LIFECYCLE_STATUS'     AS cca_lifecycle_status,
      'EQUIPMENT_TYPE'           AS equipment_type,
      'DATA_ALLOWANCE'           AS data_allowance,
      'DURATION'                 AS duration,
      'DATA_ALLOWANCE_SUP_OFFER' AS data_allowance_sup_offer
    )
  )
) src
ON (src.offer_migration_id = dst.offer_migration_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET cca_category             = NVL(dst.cca_category, src.cca_category),
      cca_lifecycle_status     = NVL(dst.cca_lifecycle_status, src.cca_lifecycle_status),
      equipment_type           = NVL(dst.equipment_type, src.equipment_type),
      data_allowance           = NVL(dst.data_allowance, src.data_allowance),
      duration                 = NVL(dst.duration, src.duration),
      data_allowance_sup_offer = NVL(dst.data_allowance_sup_offer, src.data_allowance_sup_offer);
```

Then after the `MERGE`, the table contains:

> | OFFER_MIGRATION_ID | CCA_CATEGORY | CCA_LIFECYCLE_STATUS | EQUIPMENT_TYPE | DATA_ALLOWANCE | DURATION | DATA_ALLOWANCE_SUP_OFFER |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 10001 | PD | A | Devices | *null* | *null* | *null* |
> | 20001 | *null* | *null* | *null* | 9225 | *null* | *null* |
> | 20023 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 6 | 9203 |
> | 20024 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 9203 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f407c288d6f9fd4c89c927a845fd7525)*

Comment: Apologies that I was not able to provide sample data and scripts as got busy in other urgent tasks to complete I will try to add today.  
However Thanks for this valuable in fact a very detailed possible other way do it but I just want to highlight here that the PRODUCT_CHAR table does have fixed number of columns but it has almost 184 columns and not all columns will be updated all time (in future there could be changes in list of columns require to change so we need to keep that in mind as well) 
I will sure try this out today with original tables and will let you know of outcome :)